# Cron issue with daylight savings time

Tags: cron

I have a cron job to send an email once everyday.

I actually do not know the issue, but i'm guessing it has something to do with daylight savings time.

During DST, my emails are sent one hour late for the people who observe DST and at the correct time for those who don't observe DST.

Is there a way to hold both the cases?

Comment: what is it about these emails that makes being an hour late a problem? Email explicitly does not provide a guarantee of instant delivery.

Answer (score 2):

Run the cron job at both times (DST/non-DST) and then inside your cron job's logic select the appropriate users.

Comment: What is the specific command to run it on both DST and Non DST.. beacuse one it is set, nothing can be done right ?? it is system specific. PLease can you elaborate your answer. How to toggle between DST and Non DST

Comment: Cron has no notion of DST - you'd need to set the cron job to run at the normal hour as well as one hour offset to match during DST. Then in your script, you would need to check the time and whether you are currently within DST to determine whether to run.